# What's the value of the "value" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm trying to think of a tag wiki description for the [value](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/value) tag, but I find myself having trouble describing exactly what it's supposed to refer to. The first few questions from the tag are:

1. [Calculating the total capital of a company?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/21506/7590) - This is sort of a valuation question, perhaps?
2. [How does one factor how much saving time is worth?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/11106/7590) - This is about calculating how much you value your time.
3. [U.S. Bonds Taxed Interest and Current Value](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/22211/7590) - This is roughly about figuring the current value of a bond and the tax implications.
4. [What are the advantages of paying off a mortgage quickly?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/20638/7590) - This question asks about paying off the mortgage.

I won't list others, but basically, the [value](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/value) tag seems to be used on a wide variety of questions and doesn't really add value to them (in my opinion). It isn't used that frequently, but when it is, it seems so generic that it doesn't tell me anything specific about the subject of the question.

We already have the [value-investing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/value-investing) and [stock-valuation](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-valuation) tags, which I imagine cover several of the cases where "value" may be a decent category name, and they cover it better.

Does this tag add value, or should it be removed? I don't plan to edit it out of the questions, in order to avoid filling the main page with old questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have avoided this for many many days now, but no, I don't see any point to that tag.

I don't see a common replacement, so I would just remove or replace them if I had other edits to make the question overall better.

(Unless another mod can point out that we can remove the tag without bumping everything)

Comment: Is there a way to set the tag so that it can't be used again, so that even if there aren't any other changes to make to a question (and therefore the tag isn't removed) it at least won't populate more questions? To be sure, it isn't a major problem since there aren't many questions, but if this is possible it might be a good idea.

Comment: @JohnBensin Yes, the Stack Exchange folks can black-list a tag.  We've done that already with `personal-finance`, `finance`, and `money`, for instance.  But, black-listing a tag is for extreme cases.  There may yet be a use for `value`; IMHO I wouldn't ban it, just re-tag the questions with better tags (but not all at once; over time perhaps, to avoid flooding the home page? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Right, a blacklist may be overkill. I can look through the questions tagged with it when I have a chance and retag them if necessary, at the rate of around one a week so the main page isn't flooded.

Comment: It looks like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me, I like the idea of removing it while fixing whatever might need fixing on questions where it was applied. I'd rather make it a _synonym_ of another tag if it keeps creeping in, but I'm not sure what tag that would be. If it does continue to come back, we can blacklist it.